# Slow tomcat 7 deployment without any configuration

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, jvm

Tomcat consumes about 20 mins each time to deploy, and I found it stuck at deployment stage, see below log,

**First time start will consume about 2-7 mins, then it becomes even worse each time restart.**

[image]

**Environment:**

Tomcat 7.0.57 (apache-tomcat-7.0.57.tar.gz)

VPS: Ubuntu 12.04.5x32 LTS (512M RAM)

**What I did:**

1. Create a new 'clean' VPS without any change.
2. Install JDK 7 via below scripts:

   sudo apt-get install python-software-properties

   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

   sudo apt-get update

   sudo apt-get install oracle-jdk7-installer
3. Upload apache-tomcat-7.0.57.tar.gz to root home directory.
4. Uncompress tar.gz
5. Enter bin folder to execute **chmod 777 *** and **./startup.sh**

Anybody can give a suggestion? thanks.

Comment: try setting this environment variable `tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip=*`, this could be the botleneck, you can set it in `setenv.sh`

Comment: @JigarJoshi sorry I don't find setenv.sh, doesn't it locate in bin folder?

Comment: ok lets try this one `export JAVA_OPTS="-Domcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip=*"` execute this on your terminal right before starting tomcat and give it a try

Comment: @JigarJoshi seems it doesn't take any change, still very slow

Comment: when it is stuck can you take threaddump ? and can you make sure that property was applied with JConsole or jinfo ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi I'm not sure if what I did is correct or not, `jstack PID > outfile`, but outfile is empty, it also throws `'target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded'`.

Comment: was the PID correct ?

Comment: `ps -ef  | grep tomcat` is this correct to check the PID, it returns `root 1279 1050 0 22:46 pts/0 1279 1050`

Comment: yes looks right, can you try jconsole and attach it to PID and see if the system property was applied ?

Comment: really don't know how to use jconsole to attach the process under ubuntu, can you please give an example?

Comment: jconsole comes with JDK, go to JDK/bin/jconsole and launch it it will ask you on startup

Comment: I found jconsole, how to start it?

Comment: `./jconsole` or double click

Comment: ./jconsole doesn't give any response, I can't double click because I connect to vps via ssh.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68013/discussion-between-jigar-joshi-and-z-neeson).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[after this interesting discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68013/discussion-between-jigar-joshi-and-z-neeson) we found that bottleneck was

```
"localhost-startStop-1" daemon prio=10 tid=0xa880e400 nid=0xbb9 runnable [0xa80f e000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:272)
at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator$URLSeedGenerator.getSeedBytes(See dGenerator.java:551)
at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator.generateSeed(SeedGenerator.java:1 39)
at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom$SeederHolder.<clinit>(SecureRandom .java:197)
at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(SecureRandom.java: 214)
```

it was worked around by using random seed by specifying

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"
```

note: this is less secure

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6202721